# $ \sqrt[3]{a} + \sqrt[3]{b} + \sqrt[3]{c} = \sqrt[3]{\sqrt[3]{2} -1 } $ for rational $a,b,c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, field-theory, contest-math, galois-theory

The problem is to find $a,b, c \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that

$ \sqrt[3]{a} +  \sqrt[3]{b} +  \sqrt[3]{c} = \sqrt[3]{\sqrt[3]{2} -1 }  $.

My idea: if such representation exists then* $\sqrt[3]{\sqrt[3]{2} -1 }  \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ and therefore the required representation is nothing but

$ \sqrt[3]{\sqrt[3]{2} -1 } = c_1 + c_2\sqrt[3]{2} + c_3 \sqrt[3]{4}, c_i \in \mathbb{Q}$ — decomposition by the standard basis of the extension.

*- Edit: it is not true, I checked by finding eigenvalues of multiplication by   $\sqrt[3]{2} -1 $.

But there are two problems:

1. It’s computationally hard to find the coefficients. It’s probably doable using eigenvalues but I didn’t try it yet.
2. It’s actually a school problem so no knowledge of field extension is assumed.

Comment: I guess there is no solution.

Comment: Is the problem to find a,b,c, or to decide if they exist? Please post the original problem. PS: "looks right" is not a proof.

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg to find. Also, you are right, I checked and it is not in the extension $\mathbb{Q}( \sqrt[3]{2})$.

Comment: Do you need field theory to solve or is a purely algebraical solution acceptable

Comment: @Frank W  any solution is ok, I don't even formally need this problem, I am solving it out of curiosity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $x^3=2$ so that $x^3-1=1$. Factor the left-hand side from difference of cubes and move the quadratic factor to the right.

$$x-1=\frac 1{1+x+x^2}=\frac 3{3+3x+3x^2}$$

Recalling that $x^3=2$, then we have that

$$x-1=\frac 3{1+3x+3x^2+x^3}=\frac 3{(1+x)^3}=\frac 19\left(\frac 3{1+x}\right)^3$$

In other words

$$\sqrt[3]{x-1}=\frac 3{\sqrt[3]{9}}\frac {1-x+x^2}{1+x^3}=\frac {1-x+x^2}{\sqrt[3]{9}}$$

Substitute $x=\sqrt[3]2$ to get the simplification.

$$\sqrt[3]{\sqrt[3]{2}-1}=\sqrt[3]{\frac 19}-\sqrt[3]{\frac 29}+\sqrt[3]{\frac 49}$$

Comment: Is there any way to motivate this with field or Galois theory? Because even though I understand the calculation, for me it is too "magical".

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I do not know Galois theory, which is why I asked the OP if a purely algebraic solution is acceptable. Sorry!

Comment: @Frank W: Is this the only solution except permutations?